# In R Highchart how can I color diferent portion of Line Chart with different color

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

This is my code and highchart chart:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(highchart)

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile'),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    color = 'red',
    type = 'line'
  )
```

I would like to color `blue` the the portion of my chart related to years `above 1990`.

The output should be a chart with red color line from 1952 to 1990 and blue color line from 1990 to 2005.

**It would be necessary robust only one `hc_add_series` function**.

Any help?

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

If you want to only use one `hc_add_series`, you could use [`zones`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones) with a `zoneAxis`. In the `zone` you can set the `value` and `color` you want depending on the range of your `zoneAxis`, x or y. In your case it is x which means the year 1990. Here you can use a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile'),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    type = 'line',
    zoneAxis = 'x',
    zones = list(list(value = 1990, color = 'red'), list(value = 1990, color = 'blue'))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You could create two `hc_add_series` with two `filter`s. The only problem may be that there is no data on the year 1990, so I gave you a possible option like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
#> not free for commercial and Governmental use

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile' & year <= 1990),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    color = 'red',
    type = 'line'
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile' & year > 1990),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    color = 'blue',
    type = 'line'
  )
```

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/OKsC3Yq.png)]

```r
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile' & year <= 1992),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    color = 'red',
    type = 'line'
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Chile' & year > 1991),
    hcaes(x = year, y = pop),
    color = 'blue',
    type = 'line'
  )
```

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/Z4gnORd.png)]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Is it possible tondonthis with only one `hc_add_series`?

Comment: Hi @Laura, I have edited my answer according to your comment. To use only one `hc_add_series`, you can use `zones`. Hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a different colour for the series, zones can be set up, which give the possibility of setting the colour for each range of values.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: '#f7a35c'
        }, {
            value: 10,
            color: '#7cb5ec'
        }, {
            color: '#90ed7d'
        }]
    }]
});
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.zones

Comment: This is the chalenge! I will need to "translate" this to R. I will try.